# How to compare responses of two methods in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am executing a SOPA method on two environments(Dev and UAT) in SopaUI free version and want to compare the responses to check data mismatch, please suggest any solution for the same.

Response Format-

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetAccountsResponse xmlns="http://services.multichoice.co.za/SelfCare">
         <GetAccountsResult xmlns:a="http://datacontracts.multichoice.co.za/SelfCare" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Account>
               <a:afterDue121To150>0</a:afterDue121To150>
               <a:afterDue151To180>0</a:afterDue151To180>
               <a:afterDue180UpField>0</a:afterDue180UpField>
               <a:afterDue1To30Field>0</a:afterDue1To30Field>
               <a:afterDue31To60Field>0</a:afterDue31To60Field>
               <a:afterDue61To90Field>0</a:afterDue61To90Field>
               <a:afterDue91To120Field>0</a:afterDue91To120Field>
               <a:currency>NGN</a:currency>
               <a:currentAmount>0</a:currentAmount>
               <a:defaultCurrencytotalBalance>0</a:defaultCurrencytotalBalance>
               <a:defaultCuurencyCode>NGN</a:defaultCuurencyCode>
               <a:invoicePeriod>1</a:invoicePeriod>
               <a:isPrimary>true</a:isPrimary>
               <a:lastInvoiceAmount>0</a:lastInvoiceAmount>
               <a:lastInvoiceDate>2017-02-19T15:52:54</a:lastInvoiceDate>
               <a:methodOfPayment>Cash</a:methodOfPayment>
               <a:number>3112</a:number>
               <a:paymentDueDate>2016-11-10T00:00:00</a:paymentDueDate>
               <a:segmentation>Customer Segment N</a:segmentation>
               <a:status>Suspended</a:status>
               <a:totalBalance>0</a:totalBalance>
               <a:type>Ges</a:type>
            </a:Account>
         </GetAccountsResult>
      </GetAccountsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: It is difficult without data you are having and what exactly you wanted compare. Edit the question and add details requested.

Comment: See if this is helpful - https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Groovy-XML-Comparison-Dynamic-XML-Attributes-are-not-ignored/m-p/139489#U139489

Comment: A question comes to mind when comparing environments. Will the test data retrieved be identical with certainty? Rather than comparing responses from environments I reach out to the source and I compare with the data in the database. There is a JDBC step to do that in SoapUI. DB must be accessible then off course. If I actually need to verify data in two environments I usually see this as a preparatory step. I would ask a developer to div the sets. I'm puzzled and curious as to why you want to verify data across environments through a service.

Comment: Requirement is related to data sync, that's why need to compare data of two environments to check that data is syncing properly between the databases.

Answer (score 0):

//Step 1: Set DEV environment in your soap request using `ReqProps = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("stepname as in soapui suite"
       ReqProps.setPropertyValue("Endpoint","https://dev:endpoint")`
//Step 2: Run the DEV step and save response in some variable `testRunner.runTestStepByName("stepname as in soapui suite")
      DEvResponse = ReqProps.getPropertyValue("Response")`

// Step 3: Repeat Same step for UAT environment and take response in variable UATResponse
// Step 4: Compare 2 responses using `DetailedDiff diffInRes = new DetailedDiff(new Diff(DEVRes, UATRes))

List differencesArray = diffInRes.getAllDifferences()`

// Step 5 . Take array size to verify if XMLs match. If XMLs does not match you can print differences and get all mismatches from array "differencesArray"

Comment: While executing 'DetailedDiff diffInRes = new DetailedDiff(new Diff(DEVRes, UATRes))

List differencesArray = diffInRes.getAllDifferences()` code getting 'Unable to resolve class DetailedDiff  '